# Remote attribute for validation in MVC not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, attr, unobtrusive-validation

Here is what my code look like rendered as HTML

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-remote="User name already exists. Please enter a different user name." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Name" data-val-remote-url="/OrchardLocal/Genealex.CRM.Core/Home/doesNameExist" data-val-required="Enter Name" id="typeName" name="TypeType.Name" type="text" value="">
```

Here is the property in my model

```
[Remote("doesNameExist", "Home", ErrorMessage = "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The action in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult doesNameExist(string Name)
{
    var user = _contactBll.DoesTypeExist(Name);
    if (user)
    {
        return Json("Username is already exist", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in my View I have :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TypeType.Name, new { id = "typeName" })
```

I have also included scripts like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>
```

Yet, when I leave the focus from the textbox, after I have written something in the input field the validation is not fired.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure that your action is reachable under that url `/OrchardLocal/Genealex.CRM.Core/Home/doesNameExist` - it looks oddly, moreover we do not have your routing defintion

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have found my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was the following :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult doesNameExist(string Name)
{
    var user = _contactBll.DoesTypeExist(Name);
    if (user)
    {
        return Json("Username is already exist", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Instead of [HttpPost], I needed the [HttpGet] over my controller. Switched it up and works just fine.